# Geometry parallel angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

1 picture. Find value of u, v and w

2nd picture. find value of x

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Which angles have you managed to determine? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: First picture: I know that w = 68 because it's corresponding. And 90 degrees rectangular, oh wait I suddenly got it. 90+68= 158 180-158 = 22, v=22 but how am I suppose to find u? On the second picture I tried to extend lines but still haven't figured it out because I get multiple numbers and I do not know how I am suppose to find x the way I am trying.

Comment: That should immediately tell you what $u$ is, since $w$, a right angle and $u$ are on a line.

Answer (score 0):

In the first picture, 
$90+68+u=180.$[because these angles are on one line, so their sum must be $180$]
 
So, $u=180-90-68=22$
 Now, angle u and v are equal, because they are alternate interior angles. We find that u=22. Now, given angle 68 and w are corresponding angles. So, w=68.

[image]

We drawn a line CE parallel to AD and BF. Since, 30 and angle ACX are alternate interior angles, they are equal. Similarly, 50 and angle BCX are alternate interior angles, so they are equal. Therefore, i 've add up $x=30+50=80$

Comment: First picture, It's "v" but what's the value of u? And how do you find it without looking at v. And the second picture isn't quite understandable as you just added two numbers.

Comment: Ok, wait i 'll explain more precisely.

Comment: please respond, do you understand now?

Comment: I am trying to.

Comment: tell me unhesitatingly where don't you understand.

Comment: Is there like anything behind those numbers? Any sum that we need to find? Like the triangle on the first picture which sums up to 180.

Comment: no. alternate interior angles are equal - i'm sure you don't understand this.

Comment: Read this : http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/parallel-lines.html

Comment: I m going now, dont forget to upvote and tick mark my answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Yeah I do understand the parallel but The second picture was way too easy.. Just draw another line and add characters and add two numbers?..

Comment: exactly, you are right